# Still have so many errors when I tried to import the source code into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, neo4j, m2eclipse

I followed the youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFczTgsxktQ, what I have installed right now are Eclipse 4.3 classic and maven 3 and scala m2e and scala.
I took the source code from GitHub.
I have used the following commands.

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/neo4j
git clone git://github.com/neo4j/neo4j.git
cd neo4j
git pull origin master
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
cd ..
```

Both the Eclipse and the neo4j folder are at the desktop (Linux system)
When I tried to import the existing maven project in the folder `neo4j/community`, it always has so many errors.

Errors are in the this picture:
[image: pic]

However, I can run unit test of each source file. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your projects Menu->Project->Clean...
Sometimes the Maven and Eclipse build dont work perfectly together.